# Apache Ignite SQL query composed primary key NET

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I wonder if it is possible to query in some way a certain property of an Class which I used as primary key.
My idea was something like the below code. With _key.NAME I receive and error message saying column not exist, I tried with TestOjectPK.NAME too, but without success:

```
var fieldsQuery = new SqlFieldsQuery("select _val,_key from TestObject where _key.NAME= ? and VALUE= ?", "name1","value");
IQueryCursor<IList> queryCursor = cache.QueryFields(fieldsQuery);
```

This are my classes to represent a certain table with 3 columns, where 2 of them are PK.

```
class TestObjectPK : IBinarizable
{
    private Int32 id;
    private String name;

    [QuerySqlField]
    public string NAME
    {
        get{return this.name;}
        set{this.name = value;}
    }

    [QuerySqlField]
    public Int32 ID
    {
        get{return this.id;}
        set{this.id = value;}
    }

    public void WriteBinary(IBinaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteInt("ID", ID);
        writer.WriteString("NAME", NAME);
    }

    public void ReadBinary(IBinaryReader reader)
    {
        ID = reader.ReadInt("ID");
        NAME = reader.ReadString("NAME");
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return id.GetHashCode() + name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return id == ((TestObjectPK)obj).id && name == ((TestObjectPK)obj).NAME;
    }
}


class TestObject : IBinarizable
{
    private String value2;
    [QuerySqlField]
    public String VALUE
    {
        get { return this.value2; }
        set { this.value2 = value; }
    }


    public void WriteBinary(IBinaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString("VALUE", VALUE);
    }

    public void ReadBinary(IBinaryReader reader)
    {
        VALUE = reader.ReadString("VALUE");
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return VALUE.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return VALUE == ((TestObject)obj).VALUE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All fields marked with `[QuerySqlField]` from key and value objects end up in SQL table directly.

So the correct query would be

```
select _val,_key from TestObject where NAME=? and VALUE=?
```

Also make sure to configure both key and value types for SQL:

```
new CacheConfiguration("TestObject", 
        new QueryEntity(typeof(TestObjectPK), typeof(TestObject)))
```

Comment: Pavel I tried what you said. But Ignite still throw an error related with NAME column not found. Maybe it's and error when I created the cache? 
`ICache<TestObjectPK, TestObject> cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<TestObjectPK, TestObject>(new CacheConfiguration("TestObject", typeof(TestObject)));



TestObjectPK testObjectPK = new TestObjectPK();
testObjectPK.NAME = "h1";
testObjectPK.ID = 1;
TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
testObject.VALUE = "value1";
cache.Put(testObjectPK, testObject);`
Thanks

Comment: Exactly, to use key fields in query you have to specify key type as well: `new CacheConfiguration("TestObject", new QueryEntity(typeof(TestObjectPK), typeof(TestObject)))`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. For everyone who have the same question I created a GitHub repository with the full example: https://github.com/juanpale/ExampleApacheIgniteQueryCompositeObjectNET